# Symfony using run-time parameters in services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I need to initialize an object that will be injected into some services. Some of his arguments can be obtained during run-time from request parameters.
How should I work with such dynamic objects?

The first way I found was to make setters and pass arguments throw services that use the object. But I think it's smell bad.

The second approach is to mark my object as "synthetic service". So I must prepare object in a constructor and set it to the service container.

I'm not sure that it's the best approach. Can somebody suggest me the right way to act in such situations?

Pseudo code sample of first approach:

```
class Storage {
    private $path;
    private $project;

    public function __construct($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    public function setProject($project): void {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    public function showFullPath() {
        echo "Full path: {$this->path}/{$this->project}";
    }
}

class Service {
    private $storage;

    public function __construct(Storage $storage) {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function doSomething($project) {
        $this->storage->setProject($project);
        $this->storage->showFullPath();
    }
}


// in controller
$service = $container->get('Service');
$service->doSomething($project);
```

Pseudo code sample of second approach:

```
class Storage {
    private $path;
    private $project;

    public function __construct($path, $project) {
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    public function showFullPath() {
        echo "Full path: {$this->path}/{$this->project}";
    }
}

class Service {
    private $storage;

    public function __construct(Storage $storage) {
        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        $this->storage->showFullPath();
    }
}


// in controller
$storage = new Storage($path, $project);
$container->set('Storage', $storage);

$service = $container->get('Service');
$service->doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters you need are retrieved from the request, why don't you inject the request stack into `Storage`, and then on `showFullPath` just get the parameter you need from the request's stack master request?

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class Storage {
  private $path;
  private $requestStack;

  public function __construct($path, RequestStack $requestStack) {
      $this->path = $path;
      $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
  }

  public function showFullPath() {
      $project = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getYourParametersHereFromRequest();
      echo "Full path: {$this->path}/{$project";
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it looks like work with global variables.
And I want to specify dependencies of my classes.

Comment: But it's not, you're getting it from the request. You could also create a `ParameterProvider` service that returns the parameters you need, inject the request stack there and inject `ParameterProvider` anywhere you need those parameters.

Comment: Storage shouldn't know where the project comes from.
I believe request must be handled in a controller.

Comment: Use a `ParameterProvider`, that will abstract where the parameters come from.

Comment: I think your solution will be more convenient. But it decreases purity of the Storage interface because ParameterProvider hides argument that uses in Storage.

Comment: It doesn’t hide arguments IMO, it provides them to the storage class as it’s a collaborator.

Comment: But at first it was:
`class Storage {
    __construct($path, $project) {}
}`

Now it will be:
`class Storage {
    __construct($path, ParameterProvider $params) {}
}`

So it looks like first was much cleaner.

Comment: Does it just return the full path? In that case rename to ‘StoragePathProvider’ or similar

Comment: If I understand you right it will just move the issue to another place.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gvf that the using the RequestStack approach is a good solution in this scenario. However, if you insist on using the request object from the controller, you can introduce a factory service to create the storage object:

```
class StorageFactory
{
    public function createStorage(Request $request) : Storage
    {
        // ... create $storage from $request
        return $storage;
    }
}


class Service
{
    public function doSomething(Storage $storage)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// in your controller
$storage = $container->get("storage_factory")->createStorage($request);
$container->get('Service')->doSomething($storage);
```

As you see, you will have to pass the `$storage` object as a parameter to the `doSomething` method. It is not possible to set it in the constructor, because you explicitely want to create the `$storage` object after the services have been set up.

By the way: setter injection sucks, because it allows services to be in an inconsistent state. Avoid it (and setters in general) whereever possible.

Comment: It's possible to set Storage in a constructor by using synthetic service. See this link: https://symfony.com/doc/2.4/components/dependency_injection/advanced.html#synthetic-services

Comment: @Denis: I know that this is possible, I just don’t see any advantage in doing so. The fact that this feature exists doesn’t mean that it’s a good idea to use it.